# Go directly to fragment in Navigation Drawer Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I have a navigation drawer activity with fragments in it. Now how can I make the app to go directly to a fragment when that activity is opened? I don't want to show the `content_main.xml` (which is blank):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
 @Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    //calling the method displayselectedscreen and passing the id of selected menu
    displaySelectedScreen(item.getItemId());

    return true;
}
```

private void displaySelectedScreen(int itemId) {

```
    //creating fragment object
    Fragment fragment = null;

    //initializing the fragment object which is selected
    switch (itemId) {
        case R.id.nav_menu1:
            fragment = new Menu1();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_menu2:
            fragment = new Menu2();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_menu3:
            fragment = new Menu3();
            break;
    }

    //replacing the fragment
    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
        ft.commit();
    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
}
```

> in onCreate()

```
DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    //add this line to display menu1 when the activity is loaded
    displaySelectedScreen(R.id.nav_menu1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have some options.

1) Open `activity_main.xml`

And replace a line that includes `layout=content_main` with the layout that you actually want instead.

2) Just load the Fragment in `onCreate` like you would when you do click on the Navigation Drawer.

Answer (score 0):

go to Activity onCreate method  and  put this

```
 FragmentManager fm =getFragmentManager();
 FragmentTransaction ft= fm.beginTransaction();
 // the Second paramter is Object from your Fragment that you want to add it  
ft.replace(R.id.activity_main ,fragmentObject  );
ft.commit();
```